# exclude javascript code from print function

Tags: javascript, xslt, printing

I have a print function on a page in my website. the problem is, when it hits this line:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.powerreviews.com/repos/12564/pr/pwr/engine/js/full.js"></script>`, it tries to load it, and just never finishes.

Any ideas on how to get around that?

Comment: the line didn't get in. here it is:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.powerreviews.com/repos/12564/pr/pwr/engine/js/full.js"></script>

Comment: what language are you using to do the print? PHP?

Comment: Just select the code and press the code-block icon in the editor (10101).

Comment: Does it work with a non obfuscated version?

Comment: the print is a javascript function within an xsl page.

what is a non obfuscated version?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [CSS @media rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) for this.

```
<a class="noprint">foo</a>
```

and then add a `@media print` rule to your CSS which hides the elements during print:

```
@media print {
    .noprint {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just got a chance to try this, and unfortunately, it did not work.

Any other suggestions?